# Errors in my SQLite Database for Android

Tags: android, sqlite

I am having multiple issues with my SQLite Database with Android. I am new to developing and learning on my own. SO please use laymens terms and assume i do not know what you are talking about lol. Specifically i am having trouble wit the methods:

- getLast()
- getLatestSubjectForContact()
- getAllRows()
- isEmpty()

If you see any other errors i will accept feedback. Thanks for all help you can provide. here is my database code

```
package com.swavey.testing;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.provider.BaseColumns;
import android.security.KeyChain;

import java.util.Date;

/**
 * Created by Adrian on 11/5/2014.
 */
public class smsDatabase  {

    private static final String KEY_ID = "_id";
    private static final int COLUMN_ID =0;

    // database info
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "texts";
    public static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "mainTable";
    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 4;

    // list of fields
    public static final String KEY_ADDRESS = "address";
    public static final String KEY_BODY = "body";
    private static final String KEY_DATE = "date";
    private static final String KEY_READ = "read";
    private static final String KEY_THREADID = "thread_id";
    private static final String KEY_TYPE = "type";
    private static final String KEY_SEEN = "seen";

    //list of field numbers
    private static final int COL_ADDRESS = 1;
    private static final int COL_BODY = 2;
    private static final int COL_DATE = 3;
    private static final int COL_READ = 4;
    private static final int COL_THREADID = 5;
    private static final int COL_TYPE = 6;
    private static final int COL_SEEN = 7;

    //create string array of all fields;
    public static final String[] ALL_KEYS = new String[] {KEY_ID, KEY_ADDRESS, KEY_BODY, KEY_DATE,
         KEY_READ, KEY_THREADID, KEY_TYPE, KEY_SEEN};


    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE_SQL = "create table " + DATABASE_TABLE
            + " (" + KEY_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, "
            +KEY_ADDRESS + " text not null, "
            +KEY_BODY + " text not null, "
            +KEY_DATE + " text not null, "
            +KEY_READ+ " text not null, "
            +KEY_THREADID+ " text not null, "
            +KEY_TYPE+ " text not null, "
            +KEY_SEEN+ " text not null"
            + ");";

    private final Context context;

    private DatabaseHelper dbHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase db;

    public smsDatabase (Context cxt) {
        this.context = cxt;
        dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
    }

    //open database
    public void open() {
        db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    }
    //close database
    public void close() {
        dbHelper.close();
    }

    //returns a cursor with all rows loaded
    public Cursor getAllRows() {
        String where = null;
        Cursor cursor = db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, ALL_KEYS, where, null, null, null,
        null, null);

        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        return cursor;
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        String where = null;
        Cursor cursor = db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, ALL_KEYS, where, null, null, null,
                null, null);
        if (cursor!=null) return false;
        return true;
    }


    // insert sms into table
    public long insertSMS (SMS sms) {
        ContentValues iv = new ContentValues();
        iv.put(KEY_ADDRESS, sms.getAddress());
        iv.put(KEY_BODY, sms.getBody());
        iv.put(KEY_DATE, sms.getDate());
        iv.put(KEY_READ, sms.getRead());
        iv.put(KEY_THREADID, sms.getThread_id());
        iv.put(KEY_TYPE, sms.getType());
        iv.put(KEY_SEEN, sms.getSeen());




        return db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, iv);
    }

    public Cursor getLast() {
        SMS txt = new SMS();
        String where = null;
        Cursor c = db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE,ALL_KEYS, where, null, null, null, null, null);
        c.moveToLast();
        return c;

    }

    public void deleteLast() {
        String where = null;
        Cursor c = db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE,ALL_KEYS, where, null, null, null, null, null);
        String las = Integer.toString(c.getCount());
        db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_ID + "=" + las, null);
    }

    public void deleteRow(String address, String date, String body ) {
        db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_ADDRESS + "=" + address +" and " + KEY_DATE + "=" +
        date + " and " + KEY_BODY + "=" + body, null);
    }

    public String getLatestSubjectForContact() {
        Cursor c = getLast();
        String sub = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("body"));
        if (sub.length() > 30) {
            sub = sub.substring(0, 30) + "...";
            return sub;
        }
        sub = sub +  "...";
        return sub;
    }

    private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
        DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase _db) {
            _db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE_SQL);
        }


        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase _db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            _db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+ DATABASE_TABLE);
            onCreate(_db);
        }
    }
}
```

logcat for the getLast() method:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.swavey.testing/com.swavey.testing.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 23, col -1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 23, col -1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
            at android.database.CursorWindow.nativeGetString(Native Method)
            at android.database.CursorWindow.getString(CursorWindow.java:434)
            at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:51)
            at com.swavey.testing.MainActivity.addText(MainActivity.java:144)
            at com.swavey.testing.MainActivity.initialSync(MainActivity.java:105)
            at com.swavey.testing.MainActivity.Sync(MainActivity.java:71)
            at com.swavey.testing.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:41)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: A suggestion, before trying to get data from a cursor check if the query returned something.

Comment: Like this : `if (c.getCount() > 0)`

Comment: Ok. That's a good check. I'll be sure to do that. Can you help with my question ?

Comment: Not everyone one of them throws an error. getLast() does and it throws this error

"java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.swavey.testing/com.swavey.testing.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 23, col -1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
public Cursor getLast() {
    SMS txt = new SMS();
    String query = "SELECT * FROM mainTable";
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    if(c != null && c.getCount() > 1)
       return c.moveToLast();
    return null;
}

public void deleteLast() {
    String query = "SELECT KEY_ID from mainTable order by KEY_ID DESC limit 1";
    long lastId = -1;
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    if (c != null && c.moveToFirst()) {
        lastId = c.getLong(0);
    }

    if(lastId != -1)
      db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_ID + "=" + lastId, null);
}
```

Comment: Its still throwing same error. Before this method is performed the database cursor has a correct count of 4. simply running this method returns the database cursor count of 24 and throws the error mentioned.

Comment: Its not a c is null error so that answer doesnt help. The count is 24. Most likely its something wrong with the query.

but still, whole logcat now poseted.

Comment: I think that the problem is coming from deleteLast(), i kind of rewrite it have a look.

Comment: thanks for helping me spot the error in my deleteLast but that doesnt effect the getLast method. Still an error.

Comment: rawQuery(String) is not a valid methoed. i think you forgot to include an argument, but i think where your headed is a solution.

Comment: Sorry, i forgot the second argument. Copy and paste these methods.

Comment: same error. im becoming clueless now on why this is happening.

Comment: Post your mainActivity too.

Comment: Hey issathink. It was an error with my main code. i dont know what was going on but i just rewrote all my code and cleaned it up and that error is no longer happening. thanks for your help.